# Change SVG Viewbox size with CSS

Tags: css, svg

The Question:
Is there a way to change the size of the SVG viewbox with CSS, but preserve the aspect ratio? OR is there another way to preserve the aspect ratio of the SVG without a view box.

The Problem:
I want to responsively adjust the size of the SVG, but keep the aspect ratio.  The width of the viewbox adjusts with the page, but the height doesn't adjust with the width. The problem with that is that the height of the container div is dependent on the height of the viewbox.  So the container div may be really tall even if there's nothing showing in the bottom half of the viewbox.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hT9Jb/1/

```
<style>
    div{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #00ffff;
    }

    svg{
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #ffff00;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="250px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 250 400" enable-background="new 0 0 250 400" aspect-ratio="XminYmin">
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#FF0000" width="250" height="400"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

(Object SVGs and img SVGs wont work for my purposes.  It has to be inline.  The solution doesn't have to be CSS...javascript is definitely an acceptable solution.)

Comment: looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/hT9Jb/2/

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073219/automatically-scaling-svg-at-time-of-creation

Comment: @KheemaPandey I want the div to conform to the svg, not the other way around (And the fiddle you gave me doesn't preserve the aspect ratio of the viewbox)

Comment: @Sisyphus That's all serverside, but it does give me a javascript idea.

Answer (score 41):

You could use a transform:

```
transform: scale(0.75); // 75% of original size
```

Comment: This is the best solution here imo

Comment: THis does not change the viewbox. It changes the scale. Changing the viewbox *CROPS* the SVG, it does not scale it.

Comment: This did nothing for me

Comment: As @kainaw said, this is not a solution to the question - this stretches the cropped svg, it does not alter the viewBox to show more content or change the aspect ratio.

Comment: This is not a good solution, as it leaves empty space around the SVG.

Answer (score 22):

I haven't yet found a way to change the viewBox property with CSS. However this Javascript solution works well:

```
var mySVG = document.getElementById('svg');
mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 100 100");
```

Also remove any references to width and height from the SVG and set them in CSS. Even though your working with an SVG, it's inline so cascading rules apply.

Comment: This worked fantastically. I do not think there is a CSS solution but this Javascript option achieved exactly what was needed.

Comment: There definitely is a css solution with `transform: scale(X.XX)`

Comment: If any of you wondering the numbers on the viewBox, here it is `viewBox = x y width height`

Answer (score 12):

In order to have a flexible SVG, that allows you to change its width and height, you need to **remove completely the width and height** and work with `viewbox` instead.

And, contrary to what sansSpoon said, you do not need javascript to do this.

In your css, refer to your svg and define its `max-width` and `max-height`, for example:

```
.my_svg_element {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 400px;

}
```

After that, your SVG will be elastic and, at the same time, will respect the max width and height you have defined before.

Comment: If you are scaling something like 250px width and 400px, the second line should be max-height. Or vise versa, it depends on scaling requirements. I edited it, please check.

Comment: This is the best answer !

Comment: This seems to work and let you treat svg more like an img. There is a good article on it here: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/. It seems viewBox sets the aspect ratio and that allows you to change (scale) the size using CSS. Using d3 to create the svg:     .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h + "") 
and then some CSS with 
         .svg {
            width: 10%;
            height: auto;
        }
or you can scale the surrounding <div>

Comment: You can experiment with a codepen here: https://codepen.io/martin-harvey/pen/RwpgdpY. Change the CSS for #graph and .svg to scale the svg while maintaining aspect ratio. To modify a CodePen, hit Change View > Editor View.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try:

```
preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin'
```

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/hT9Jb/3/

For more details, see [mozila documentation about svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Comment: Yes...preserveAspectRatio preserves the aspect ratio of the SVG within the viewbox, but does not preserve the aspect ratio of the viewbox.

Comment: This does not solve my problem. Thanks though. Interesting.

Answer (score 6):

The width and height values specified in your SVG are the cause of your problem.

The solution is to fix your SVG file.  Change:

```
width="250px" height="400px"
```

to

```
width="100%" height="100%"
```

Or with CSS:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: I understand the question is about setting CSS values around the source svg. Not creating dozens of svg files with slightly different values.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer on @Paulo Coghi which is the best answer for me (and who saved me after a few hours of failing tests and useless googling:

Just tranform your svg from:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="250px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 250 400" enable-background="new 0 0 250 400" aspect-ratio="XminYmin">
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#FF0000" width="250" height="400"/>
</svg>
```

into:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 250 400" >
    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#FF0000" width="250" height="400"/>
    // and/or whatever you want
</svg>
```

then you can use in your CSS:

```
svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    // or any other units or measurements you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    svg{
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #000;
    }
```

```html
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="250px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 250 400" enable-background="new 0 0 250 400" aspect-ratio="XminYmin" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#FF0000" width="250" height="400"/>
    </svg>
```

Just use this and see if it works(worked for me).

```
<svg .... .... ...  preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

This should work.

Comment: The `preserveAspectRatio` worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform on the inner tags of the svg, example the g tag
`svg g { transform: translate(16px, 16px); }`

Answer (score -3):

I found a simple javascript solution:

```
function setSvgSize(){
    var width = document.getElementById('svg-container').offsetWidth;
    var x = parseInt( $('#svg').attr('width') );
    var y = parseInt( $('#svg').attr('height') );
    var height = (width / x) * y;
    $('#svg-container').css('height',height);
}
```