# how to control svg viewBox by css

Tags: html, css, svg

in the example below I can control everything about svg using css - except the viewBox?
how to do this?
I tried `.shadow viewBox{..}` and remove the params from markup - doesn't work

```css
.wrap{
background:gold;
width:70%;
height:54px;
position:relative;
}
.shadow{
    position:absolute;
    right:25px;
    bottom:5px;
    width:7%;
}

.shadow path{
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<svg class="shadow" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
<g>
<path d="M213.1,6.7c32.4-14.4-73.7,0-88.1,30.6C110.6,4.9,67.5-9.5,36.9,6.7C33.3,64.2,247.2,22.9,213.1,6.7z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: viewBox is an attribute and CSS cannot affect or override attributes.

Comment: @RobertLongson - `style='...'` is also attribute, isn't it?

Comment: So what? That's the other way round i.e. an attribute setting CSS not CSS setting/overriding an attribute.

Comment: how about javascript? - `element.setAttribute('viewBox', value)`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov - I prefer to avoid js for layout

Comment: describe what you are trying to achieve. I am pretty sure it can be done without messing with the viewbox

Comment: but you can't vary `viewBox` values without javascript. but still, look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463096/change-svg-viewbox-size-with-css

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I have some design-rich pages, with a lot of vignettes, shadow-figures etc. And want to use the `same` figure in different size and position on page Problem - sometimes I must to change viewBox params in markup - and want to avoid this

Comment: That's what the <use> element is for. You can have lot's of <use> elements with different viewBox attributes pointing to the same content.

Comment: @RobertLongson - any example, pls

Comment: @TemaniAfif - maybe better explanation - my svg figures are inside php files - used by `include()` and want to include the same file on many positions and sizes - and control the params by css

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Comment: I still don't see why you need to adjust the viewbox. The viewBox should be something fixed based on the content and never change (like all the online libraries are doing)

Comment: to change the size and position of something you'd use a transform or width/height attributes, as @TemaniAfif says viewBoxes are normally constant.

Comment: @TemaniAfif -  because if I have a viewBox 0 0 50 50 - it is suitable for a small figures but it not if a figure goes over entire page. If I set te viewBox always on full dimensions of  page (and how to do this) - I'm afraid this is not the right way

Comment: @RobertLongson - how a size of anything can be constant? I'm using `svg` instead of png just because of large scalling the images

Comment: I think you are confusing viewBox and width/height. A viewbox will limit the area of the SVG and it can be scaled at any dimension you want. viewBox is not related to sizing

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I already tried - `0 0 100% 100%` - and getting syntax error. because some figures go over entire page, and I cannot know the pixels values

Comment: I advise you to learn more around viewBox, it has nothing to do with dimension and sizing. It's not the one to update to make a figure go full page. viewBox depend only on the content inside it, it's not related in any way to how the SVG should be sized in the document.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - it is clear to me - not related to size - but related to visibility entire figure or just a part. So problem is how to ensure the visibility of entire figure regardles of its size

Comment: visibility can be handled with overflow, not viewbox. You consider specific width/height of a container or something else and you hide the overflow

Comment: @TemaniAfif - if a viewBox is smaller than a svg figure - the figure is cutted - not visible entirelly. How to set the viewBox to be responsive - or - allways on max values - so any size of svg can be visible entirely

Comment: If you set a valid viewBox then your drawing is naturally responsive. Note that a valid viewBox consists of 4 unitless numbers.