# Styling toast container by applying a SCSS class

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-toastify

I am trying to style the `react-toastify` toast container:

```
<ToastContainer style={{width: "30%"}} className="toast"
    position="top-center"
    etc.
/>
```

Here is the SCSS:

```
.toast {
    width: 30%; // affects the text, not the container
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    & img {
        width: 3rem; // no effect
    }
}
```

`width: 30%` in the style attribute works as expected, i.e. sets the width of the *container*. Why does the same property in the class affect the *text*, i.e. makes the text narrow?

The styling of `img` is an attempt to make the icon larger. I suspect that this attempt fails because the icon is a character, not an image. However, I could not find how to set it's font size. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Here is what I see in the element explorer:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if I should ask this as two separate questions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `react-toastify` but everything depends on what `<ToastContainer` renders, is it a div? Is the class `toast` applied to it?

Comment: @Azu I have pasted the elements into the question. `Toastify__toast_container` has `toast` applied to it...

Comment: As I can see, the inline style `style={{width: "30%"}}` is applied to the `.toast` container. If you remove it, it's very possible that some of the classes before `toast` to set the `width`. You say it's applied to the text... unfortunately it's not visible from the screenshot where the text is.
Is the `svg` icon you;d like to enlarge? Then use `& svg`.

Comment: Setting `width` and `height` for `svg` does not change the icon's size. It seems like the size is controlled by `viewBox`. But how so I change it?

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463096/change-svg-viewbox-size-with-css, transform did the job. Thanks!